# Sort order settings for LC_COLLATE to get 'a' < 'A' < 'b' < 'B'

Tags: linux

Is there a setting for `LC_COLLATE` to get the sort order: `'a' < 'A' < 'b' < 'B'`? (see output at the end of this post).  Note: `'A' < 'a' < 'B' < 'b'` is also okay.  Here's an example to illustrate the problem.

First, we create a bunch of empty files in a temporary folder as follows:

```
$ mkdir temp
$ cd temp
$ cat ../echo-scr 
echo > a-a
echo > a-b
echo > a-A
echo > a-B
echo > B-a
echo > B-b
echo > B-A
echo > B-B
echo > aa-a
echo > aa-A
echo > aA-a
echo > aA-A
echo > Aa-a
echo > Aa-A
echo > AA-a
echo > AA-A
$ bash ../echo-scr
```

With the setting `"LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8"`, the problem is that the files starting with `'a'` are split into two groups (`'a' < 'A'` is not respected):

```
$ export LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8; /bin/ls -1
a-a
a-A
aa-a
aa-A
aA-a
aA-A
Aa-a
Aa-A
AA-a
AA-A
a-b
a-B
B-a
B-A
B-b
B-B
```

Apparently `"LC_COLLATE=C"` keeps the files starting with `'a'` together, but creates another problem--now we get `'A' < 'B' < 'a' < 'b'`, but what we want is `'A' < 'a' < 'B' < 'b'` (the following sort order is also fine: `'a' < 'A' < 'b' < 'B'`).

```
$ export LC_COLLATE=C; /bin/ls -1
AA-A
AA-a
Aa-A
Aa-a
B-A
B-B
B-a
B-b
a-A
a-B
a-a
a-b
aA-A
aA-a
aa-A
aa-a
```

So the question is: what value of `LC_COLLATE` should I use to get the following sort order - `'a' < 'A' < 'b' < 'B'` (example output below)?

```
a-a
a-A
a-b
a-B
aa-a
aa-A
aA-a
aA-A
Aa-a
Aa-A
AA-a
AA-A
B-a
B-A
B-b
B-B
```

Comment: Note that what's happening with `en_US.UTF-8` is that the dashes are being ignored. You might look into `sort -t` or something.